# SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener called three times

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences

I have this code in my `onClickHandler` inside an `Activity`:

in `onCreate`:

```
final SharedPreferences prefs = this.getSharedPreferences(
      "com.example.app", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
prefs.registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(lListener);
```

in my click method:

```
int lAborted = prefs.getInt("aborted", 0); 
lAborted++;
prefs.putInt("aborted",lAborted).commit();
```

my `OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener`:

```
public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences prefs, String key) {
    mServletExecutor.updateStatistic(key);
  }
```

I dont know why but the Changelistener is called three times after commit was executed.
That leads to unnecessary server traffic. I would expect only one call...

Do you see the problem?

Thx for your help

Stefan

Comment: I agree it should be called only once,  but sth like a flag variable should solve your problem ;)

Comment: Is it possible your `onCreate()` is being invoked several times, causing the listener event to be hooked several times?

Comment: @ingamedeo: I know but I dont want to implement around the problem.

Comment: @gknicker: when the onCreate method is called? I thought only during the first creation of the activity?

Comment: @Stefan Beike I see you point ;)

Comment: lListener is a class member. created only one time...

Comment: I guess several preferences are changed (under different `key`s).

Comment: no. it is always the same key